# Whatsapp Voice Note not playing on my Lumia 520

Tags: whatsapp, voicemail

After the latest update from Whatsapp today, I am unable to play my voice notes.  Nothing happens when I press the play button.  I can send voice notes and the person receives and plays them just fine. If I forward the notes they become music files and I can play then. Help!!i I have a Lumia 520